# Bash if-check not working

Tags: command-line, bash

I want to compare strings in Bash using `if` statements, but it doesn't work:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
os=`lsb_release -r | sed 's/.*://'`
echo $os
if [ $os="16.04" ]
then
echo "g"
elif [ $os="14.04" ]
then
echo "b"
else
echo "c"
fi
```

Comment: add some spaces around your "=".... `if [ $os = "16.04" ]`....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Bash's `test` (synonym for `[ ... ]`) builtin, and also for the usually preferable `[[ ... ]]` expressions, you must separate all arguments and operators with spaces.

Furthermore, you should always quote your variables. It's also recommended to use indentation to make your code better readable and to use the new-style process substitution syntax `$(...)` instead of `` `...` ``.

Oh, and `lsb_release` has a `-s` or `--short` option to omit the first column, you don't need to parse it with `sed`.

It could look e.g. like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
os=$(lsb_release -rs)
echo "$os"
if [[ "$os" = "16.04" ]] ; then
    echo "g"
elif [[ "$os" = "14.04" ]] ; then
    echo "b"
else
    echo "c"
fi
```

On the other hand, for comparing one variable against multiple values, [`case` might be prettier](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_03.html):

```
#!/bin/bash
os=$(lsb_release -rs)
echo "$os"
case "$os" in
    "16.04") echo "g" ;;
    "14.04") echo "b" ;;
    *) echo "c" ;;
esac
```